# jQuery accordion: some parts expand, some don't

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

So i have this accordion that's working pretty well (many thanks to thanks to this community), but i'm stuck on one part : how do i get the images to stay centered whil the text box expands  on click (more obvious on the click of the first image in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KmP6u/)) and then get the text box to "unexpand" when some other image is hovered on?

Comment: The images are not displayed on the fiddle

Comment: i know, but the thumbs are to size (75px*75px) so doesn't really matter here..

Comment: so? anyone? i'm really stuck here, been trying some other things, but it's still not working..